# how can I fix this TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when counting the alphabet?

Tags: python-3.x, int

I have an error when I run this code Python 3.6.5:

```
x=0
f=open('in_a.txt',encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    h = len(line)
    for i in h:
        if line =="a"or line == "A":
            x+=1
            continue
print("this documents have%d A or a characters"  %(x))
```

then the error shows here:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is the words in the file:(just a test,I type it indiscriminately)

Asdf j213k as kfjas 932kk s8aklsd
Asd klfj 823kjds
23ksad f9ksdaf
asdfj89as df8kasdf

The result should be **:** ***this documents have 10 A or a characters***

Any ideas?I think the oroblem might be in line 5 : for i in h:

**But why?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the `str.count()` function like:

```
with open('in_a.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print('this documents have {} A or a characters'.format(
        f.read().lower().count('a')))
```

Comment: But error everywhere -_- ( f.read().lower().count('a')))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: another here: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\練習題\零基礎入門班\ch09\ch09_try.py", line 2, in <module>
    print('this documents have {} A or a characters'.format())
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: are you sure you're coding in python 3?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am using python 3.6.  Your error message shows `format()`.  Note the closed parenthesis.  This does not match my answer...

Comment: That's weird.You give an indent after the print